# C++ Windows Service application Crash on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c++, windows, boost, windows-services, windows-server-2008

**Windows Service Error:**

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

**Event Log Error Recorded:**

Faulting application [applicationname].exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x541e3f33, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00000000, process id 0x12c, application start time 0x01cfd54841eed684.

**Libraries used:**

- Several Boost(1.55.0) Libraries: chrono, date_time, filesystem, iostreams, log, system, thread, zlib
- OpenSSL(1.0.1i): libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll
- ZMQ: libzmq.dll, czmq.dll

When run as LocalSystem Privilege:
The same application works without any problem in Windows Server 2003, 
but on Window Server 2008, it crashes instantly.

When run as Administrator, it's work in both 2003 and 2008 server.

How do I debug this problem?

I don't think there is any problem with the code, coz if there was, I wouldn't have been able to run it in my local (Windows8) and Windows server 2003.

Here is the code for reference anyway.
http://pastebin.com/zxh52Xdm

Comment: One bug which should be fixed first: the `ControlHandler` function needs to be declared `WINAPI`.  If that doesn't resolve the problem, you may need to attach a debugger to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: I am not able to attach debugger, because the program crashes without running the main function.

Comment: Without running `main()` ?  That means the crash is in the C runtime (unlikely) or one of the DLL initialization routines.  You should be able to narrow it down by removing the DLLs one by one, or by using Process Monitor (available from Microsoft's web site) to see which DLL was loaded last.

Comment: Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston
I just found that when i remove this header
 
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>


from code, everything works good. 

I did run the Process Monitor, but didn't find any useful information of where the problem is. 
Here is the link to Process Monitor Log file.
http://www.filedropper.com/logfile_1

Comment: If you copy the `ssl.hpp` header content directly into your code you may be able to identify the specific cause by process of elimination.  It might also be sensible to ask on one of Boost's mailing lists or a Boost-specific forum as well as here.

Comment: @HarryJohnston TBH it sounds much more likely that the header is not the issue, but rather at runtime a dependency DLL is missing or (worse) incompatible version. OP: Try copying the required SSL ddls into your target folder so they get found at runtime.

Comment: @sehe: I wouldn't normally expect to see a null pointer dereference because of a missing/mismatched DLL, but now that you point it out, I can see how that could happen - the programmer would have to be pretty careless though.  (Not you, Pritesh, whoever developed the library that is causing the problem.)  Since removing the header prevents the crash, I'm guessing it either contains a global declaration of a type with a non-trivial initialization, or adds a DLL to the import list.  Identifying the exact trigger could be a useful clue.

Comment: (If the problem can be identified specifically enough, it should also be filed as a bug against the responsible library.)